# Access Resource files inside server tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

Hi I am stuck when I am trying to access the resource file from a server tag.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title ="<%= SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:WebPartZoneTitle_Header", "TestResource", SPContext.Current.Web != null ? SPContext.Current.Web.Language : 1033) %>" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly">
```

This throws a Exception telling Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs

Isn't there anyways that I can access resource file inside a server tag.
I have tried `<%$ Resources:WebResources, ReqLodgeName %>` this format as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Title property of your control in the code-behind of your page. That not only works, it is much cleaner as well.

Comment: the problem is I cannot got to the code behind because I am accessing this from a page layout which actually doesn't have a code behind.

Comment: @Mafas: Open your ASPX file in Visual Studio and type F7; that will take you to the code behind of the page.

Comment: Buddy as I have mentioned page layout does not have ascx.cs file associated with it.only the .ascx file exist.